# Speech recognizer datetime in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, speech-recognition

I'm working with .NET speech recognizer and I'm trying to make an alarm clock.

So I need that the speech recognizer understands dates, and the way I'm doing it is adding to the grammar all the posible values of an hour in a day like this:

```
private SemanticResultKey GetClockValues()
    {
        DateTime start = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

        DateTime end = start.AddDays(1);

        Choices choices = new Choices();

        while (start < end)
        {
            choices.Add(start.ToShortTimeString());

            start = start.AddMinutes(1);
        }

        return new SemanticResultKey("value", choices);
    }
```

Is there a better way? I hope so!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: see this http://blog.vascooliveira.com/speech-recognition-and-synthesis-with-net-3-0/ - the section Synthesizer.SpeakAsync("It's " + DateTime.Now.Hour + " hours, and " + DateTime.Now.Minute + " minutes.");